# ORA-01804: failure to initialize timezone information

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

While connecting to local installed Oracle database 18c from sql developer. I get the below error :

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01804: failure to initialize timezone information
```

same error is observed while running CREATE USER queries from sqlplus.

Solutions/suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Where in the world are you? We (Java/jdbc) look at your os locale and attempt to set the NLS parameters appropriately. You may need to set this manually for your locale.

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle JDBC driver upon connecting to your Oracle Database, looks at your OS locale to determine the proper environment for your connection.

If your locale is on the exotic side, the Database may not have a compatible Language or Region to match.

You can override what your OS is telling the JDBC driver by manually setting it in the sqldeveloper.conf file

Here's an example to set it to the United States

```
AddVMOption -Duser.region=US
```

Comment: How about the same error at sqlplus , can we set this using query /sql script.

Comment: For SQLplus your region should be defined by `NLS_LANG` variable.